# What does ‘bright light’ mean?

Tags: noun-phrases, attributives

Does ‘bright light’ mean ‘light giving out or reflecting much light’? I don’t understand what it means.

Is it like ‘drinking water’ or ‘cooking oil’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [light](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/light) in this context means a source of light

> a piece of equipment that produces light, such as a lamp or a bulb:

But a lamp can give off very little light, and be a dim light, or a lot of it, and be a bright light.

Comment: "A bright light" can refer to the source, but it can also refer to the radiation itself.